# Comparing a string in a NSMutableArray to a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm very new to objective-c and this question may seem very simple so I am sorry if it is. I  think I know how to get a user to input a string in C and comparing that to a string in an array by using strcmp. For instance (not sure if code is right as I'm not very good at c either)

```
    char *arr[2];
    arr[0] = "hello";
    arr[1] = "goodbye";

    char myString[10];
    printf("enter greeting\n");
    scanf("%s",myString);


    if(strcmp(myString,arr[0]) == 0 )
    {
        printf("hello to you to");
    }

    if(strcmp(myString,arr[1]) == 0 )
    {
        printf("goodbye then");
    }
```

But I'm trying to do the same thing with NSMutableArrays and NSStrings. So far it goes:

```
    NSMutableArray *myStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myStringArray addObject:@"hello"];
    [myStringArray addObject:@"goodbye"];


    char greetingStr[40];
    printf("enter greeting\n");
    scanf("%s", greetingStr);

    NSString *greeting = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:greetingStr];
    //Some method to compare the strings
```

I was wondering what the code is the compare NSString with objects in NSMutableArrays. Sorry if it was badly explained but I am very new to programming and please keep any answers quite simple as I'm still very new to this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Some method to compare the strings" is:

[`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_), if you're only interested in equality of strings;

[`compare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-compare_), if you also want to get information about their lexicographical ordering.